# What happens if I factory reset the phone after upgrading to Lollipop?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, factory-reset

I have updated the OS from Kitkat to Lollipop using system update. Now I want to factory reset. Does anyone know that after the factory reset Lollipop OS remains or it reverts to Kitkat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A factory reset only clears the user data from the device, it doesn't touch the system partition which is where the update was applied.

So yes, the Lollipop upgrade remains.

Comment: And if suppose I want to revert back to Kitkat OS then what can I do ?

Comment: You will have to get the KitKat stock ROM for your device and flash it manually, there is no built-in way to downgrade.